# Initialize a matrix with the number of customers in each segment today and after 10 periods - R To Python

Tags: python, r, loops, matrix

I have data

transition

```
                      2015                 2016           2017         2018         2019
  seg_1            0.962060703        0.000000000     0.000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000
  seg_2            0.896888063        0.000000000     0.000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000
  seg_3            0.000000000        0.675675676     0.000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000
```

```
-- table(customers_2015$segment) --- this variable looks like below:   
     seg_1      seg_2     seg_3   
     9158       1903      119  

-- levels(customers_2015$segment) --- this variable looks like below:
     seg_1  seg_2 seg_3
```

#### R Code

```
# Initialize a matrix with the number of customers in each segment today and after 10 periods
   segments = matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
    segments[, 1] = table(customers_2015$segment)
    colnames(segments) = 2015:2019
    row.names(segments) = levels(customers_2015$segment)
    print(segments)
    
   # Compute for each an every period
   for (i in 2:5) {
       segments[, i] = segments[, i-1] %*% transition
    }

> print(segments)
                  2015       2016       2017       2018       2019       
Seg_1            9158    10517.3299 11539.4037  12636.0028   12940.3737 
Seg_2            1903    1584.4719  1710.7998     873.8794     820.9486   
Seg_3             119     143.5516   164.5264     159.9884     156.4070
```

### Python

```
segments = np.zeros((3, 5))
column_names = ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']
row_names  = ['seg_1', 'seg_2', 'seg_3']
pd.DataFrame(segments, columns = column_names, index = row_names)
 
-----
-----
```

- I am not sure this right way in first place.
- Also I want to fill those rows and columns using the df as its done in `R`

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post what this line `print(segments)` gives you? (for R code)

Comment: @KirtimanSinha i have updated question with `print(segments) `

Comment: two questions: 1) What does `segments` look like before matrix multiplication? 2) Your `transition` matrix is the first matrix, yes?

Comment: @KirtimanSinha well, i shared everything in question. it might help if you go through it.